# Find most frequent phone number from given .txt file

Tags: python

For example: 
me.txt (which conatains data as well as phone numbers)which has below info

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

1.Phone number 1: (999) 999-3333
2.phone number 2: (888) 999 -2212
3.Phone number 3: (111) 222 - 2223
4.Phone number 4: (999)999-3333
5.Phone number 5: (888)222-2222
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

6.Phone number:  (999)999-3333
```

so the **o/p** should be : (999)999-3333 - 3 times

My try:

```
txtFile = urllib.urlopen("http:// me.txt").readlines()
txtFile = "".join(char for char in txtFile if char.isdigit()) #removes everything that's not numeric.

phone_counter = {}
for phone in txtFile.split(" "): # split in every space.

    if len(phone) > 0 :
        if phone not in phone_counter:  
            phone_counter[phone] = 1
        else:
            phone_counter[phone] += 1

for i,phone in  enumerate(sorted(phone_counter,key=phone_counter.get,reverse=True)[:-1]):
    print "%s: %s - %s"%(i+1,phone,phone_counter[phone])
```

This way I can't read numbers .Looking for **python** solution

Comment: *"is it the right way"* - have you tested it? Does it work? If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please give a [mcve] to clarify the problem.

Comment: It's obviously not the right way, since txtFile is empty when you enter your **phone** loop.  You didn't run this to see what it does (even after fixing the syntax error; I did it).

Answer (score 3):

You just need `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

text = '''\
(999) 999-3333
(888) 999-2212
(111) 222-2223
(999) 999-3333
(888) 222-2222
(999) 999-3333    
'''

counter = Counter()
for phone in text.split('\n'):
    counter[phone] += 1

print counter.most_common(1)
```

Comment: You're great answer almost justifies the poor question that prompted it. This reveals the posters question as a common task (useful to others), and reveals the idiom to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in the code.  I fixed the indentation error on the last line.  Next, your approach has to iterate through the characters of the file; **readlines** returns a list of strings, one per line.  Your second line necessarily returns null, because there's no entire line that will satisfy **isdigit**.

Also, note that stripping out all the non-digits would leave you with a string of 60 digits.  I don't think this is what you want.

I strongly recommend you start over and use incremental programming: write a couple of lines to retrieve the input.  Debug those.  Do not advance until those work.  *Then* you can write the processing you want for detecting phone numbers.

Thanks to the other answer, all you need do from here is to separate the file into phone numbers on separate lines.  Be careful: the phone numbers have embedded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file seems to have some non-related stuff around it. Taking just the numbers will make the numbers unreadable as they are merged with random numbers in the text.

Since I can't tell the exact format of the phone numbers on a line, you can use a regex to extract the number from a line.

You can also use a `collections.Counter`, as in the above answer.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

NUMBER_RE = re.compile(r'\((\d{3})\)\s?(\d{3})\s?-\s?(\d{4})')
                     #    \d{3} = 3 digits
                     #       \s? = optional space

def format_number(re_match):
    """Makes sure that the spacing is consisten to count them properly"""
    return '({0[0]}) {0[1]} - {0[2]}'.format(re_match)

txtFile = urllib.urlopen("http:// me.txt").readlines()

counter = Counter()
for line in txtFile:
    for match in NUMBER_RE.findall(line):
        counter[format_number(match)] += 1

most_common = counter.most_common(1)[0]
print("'{0[0]}' appears {0[1]} times.".format(most_common))
```